# Laravel only add alpha_num if certain conditoin is meet

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-8

How can I only add `alpha_num` to the validation if `$this->language()` returns `en`?

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => ['required', 'alpha_num'],
    ];
}

public function language()
{
    // For brevity I only return "en", it could be other languages
    return 'en';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => ['required', Rule::when($this->language() === 'en', ['alpha_num'])],
    ]; 
}
```